# "zsh: command not found: $" on Mac. Is this a problem?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew

Working my way through a Playwright Automation course, and I keep getting this error only about $. If I exclude a $ then everything executes correctly. I assume it could be an issue with homebrew, but homebrew appears to be installed correctly.

**collinbrown udemy-playwright % $ npm init
zsh: command not found: $**
**collinbrown udemy-playwright % npm init** (You can see it works if I exclude the $ that was used in the tutorial video.)
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help init` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
package name: (udemy-playwright)

Comment: I'm guessing the `$` simply stands for "This is a prompt" in the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

The `$` means that it's a shell prompt for a normal user. Since there is the root user who has all eternal powers (can be activated using the `sudo` comand), root uses `#`. So:
`$`: Normal User (like your own account)
`#`: Super User (root)

So to summarize:
If it's a `$`, you remove it.
If it's a `#`, you replace it with `sudo` (but be careful for anything with `sudo`).